# SQL self-referencing query. JOIN

Tags: sql, self-reference

i need to query a self referencing relationship for unit prerequisites.

i know that you need to use two Joins, do i SELECT my column and then join it to itself ?

```
SELECT u.unit_code,
   u.name + ' is a prerequisite of ' + u.name AS unit_prerequisite

FROM units AS u
```

so far that is what i have, not sure where my joins have to be made? not even sure if that first part is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this by joining the table to itself on the self-referencing column:

```
SELECT 
    u.unit_code, 
    u1.name + ' is a prerequisite of ' + u2.name AS unit_prerequisite 
FROM 
    units AS u1
    inner join units u2 on u2.RefId = u1.RefId
```

Comment: the issue is u2.name does not exist. see i only have one column for the name of the unit. and both sides of the select statement come from the 1 column. I'm confused as to where u2 etc is coming from

Comment: well that's how you perform a self referencing join. Perhaps you are asking some other question???

Comment: ahhh so i actually was overlooking a column and have implemented it in the way you described. thanks!

Comment: There is no typo. I'm using the same column names as the poster.

Answer (score 0):

You will need you `JOIN` to itself, similar to this:

```
SELECT u1.unit_code,
   u1.name + ' is a prerequisite of ' + u2.name AS unit_prerequisite

FROM units  u1
INNER JOIN units u2
    ON u1.id = u2.id
```