# SQL How to Select a returned value in the same statement

Tags: sql, select

I don't really know how to make a specific question for this problem, so i will try my best to explain the scenario

The table in question has the following columns.

```
**Table#1 Patients**
-PatID
-Name
-Guarantor FK_PatID (Refer to Patients Table)
```

Okay lets say i want to select Patient's name, and his guarantor's name in the table from a single SQL query.

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Guarantor
FROM Patients P
```

This statement will get me the patient's name and Guarantor's PatID, but how can I match that guarantor's ID to get it's Name in the same SQL statement?

Comment: Unlikely. More like a dev who's new to SQL.

Comment: You do have actually have the guarantor's name right?  maybe in a 2nd table?

Comment: Maybe the guarantor is in the same table because he could also be a patient. I would use one table for people, and another for the relations between them.

Comment: nvm. I see. it is confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join a table on itself

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Guarantor, P2.Name
FROM Patients P
INNER JOIN Paitents P2 on P2.PatId = P.Guarantor
```

Comment: Thank You.. This is what im looking for =)

Answer (score 0):

This is Classic example of **[SELF JOIN](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/selfjoins.htm)**

```
SELECT 
P1.Name, 
P1.Guarantor+ 'is Guarantor of' +P2.Name
FROM Patients P1
INNER JOIN Paitents P2 on P2.PatId = P1.Guarantor
```

A similar **[STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862633/sql-self-referencing-query-join)**

Answer (score -1):

```
Select p.name from Patients p where
p.guarantor in (select p1.guarantor from patients p1 where name = 'foo')
```

This will get you the names of the guarantors for all the patients called *foo*. You simply use a query in the where clause of another query.

Comment: The IN operator here is kind of a kludgy way to accomplish a self-join on a 1:1 relation.